# Android method implementations for background service

Tags: android, sqlite, background-process, background-service

Here's the situation.

I have an app with a database.
The db must update every X minutes.
The data is on a web server.
The communication with the server will take about 10 httpget requests.
So far accomplished a background service and a HTTPget function for getting the new information and updating the db.
The problem is that it must update in background at that X minutes.
I'm unsure what and how to realize that.

1.Use a delay function and run it at every X minutes ?
2.Use a sleep thread and wake it up at every X minutes ?

Or something else ?

Comment: So far.. by the 2 answers I have:No Set alarm in the manifest.Service on boot and setting alarm after X time.Alarm is called successfully and everything is ok. How is it working without the permission ? Tested on 5.0 emulator and on my S4 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

use alarm manager to trigger the event after some time, in your case you have to start sending request to server after every x minutes.. refer here http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/scheduling-task-using-alarm-manager.html

> [repeating alarm android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Intent Service](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fapp%2FIntentService.html&ei=N3sWVay7H8SRuASpkILYDg&usg=AFQjCNEIhSSDnLd7U92zu9Pcp_0BfC1_gw&bvm=bv.89381419,d.c2E) and run it periodically every X minutes using [alarm manager](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fapp%2FAlarmManager.html&ei=THsWVbHeAYOvuQTk_4HIDg&usg=AFQjCNE1Xy99Kn5P4zGr8t2xbOOAlbSMQQ&bvm=bv.89381419,d.c2E).

Use a [Broadcast Receiver](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fcontent%2FBroadcastReceiver.html&ei=YnsWVeGOBI3auQTf-oHIDg&usg=AFQjCNH03p-pz2dqqdiGMIA_Twr7g7fwxg&bvm=bv.89381419,d.c2E) to trigger  the intent service , so that the service continues to run even when user switches on their phone

Step 1. Create your Intent Service

```
public class SimpleIntentService extends IntentService {


    public SimpleIntentService() {
        super("SimpleIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
 // TODO your task

    }
}
```

Step 2. Repeating pending intent for service using AlarmManager

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, StartMyServiceReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);

        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
```

Step 3. In order to ensure that your service runs even after switch off when phone boots up again , create an PowerEventReceiver

```
public class PowerEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            //start your service
        }

    }
}
```

P.S: Remember to register your service and receivers in In AndroidManifest.